# Issue with seeding in sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, seeding

I'm doing example from sequelize docs, I created user table with:

`npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string`

Run migration and then when I run this seed:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'demo@demo.com',
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      updatedAt: Date.now()
    }], {});
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  }
};
```

Got error:

`column "createdAt" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type bigint`

Updates:

`new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')` solved problem, but don't look really nice. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Date.now()` which gives you a epoch timestamp. Instead use `new Date(). toISOString ()`  which return a ISO date string.

Comment: Now I get `time zone "gmt+0300" not recognized`. And the value of Date() is `Thu Jul 11 2019 11:25:42 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time)`